# Trying to set up a background image through css, but its not showing up

Tags: html, css

Here is my code

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id ="wrapper"class="container clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and here is my css

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient( #5Dcfc3 20%, #009E8E 75%);
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient( #5Dcfc3 20%, #009E8E 75%);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient( #5Dcfc3 20%, #009E8E 75%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial,( #5Dcfc3 20%, #009E8E 75%));
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient( #5Dcfc3 20%, #009E8E 75%);
  background-image: -ms-radial-gradient( #5Dcfc3 20%, #009E8E 75%);
}

#header {
  width: 200px;
  height: 299px;
  background: #34cfbe url("img/Trentnavbar.png") repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

So basically im trying to set a background image for my navigation bar, but when i try to add height and width it effects the background image in the class body.  Not sure what im doing wrong :(

Comment: Please set up a http://jsfiddle.net for us to play with

Comment: It's working well : http://jsfiddle.net/7pSXU/

Comment: Can you rephrase the question?   Are you trying prevent something from resizing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g7t9q/

Comment: Ok so I have a background color, and Im trying to add a Image through css for my Navigation bar(the bar that says home, contact..ect).  But the image is not showing up.

Comment: But for some reaso Alvaro the height and width for #header is messing with the gradient for that background color. and I can not get my image to show up, but i Know im calling it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Use the relative path as below.

```
#header {
  width: 200px;
  height: 299px;
  background: #34cfbe url("../img/Trentnavbar.png") repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: but the height and width is effecting the background color, instead of just the background image